# jena-fuseki: no results returned

Tags: lucene, jena, fuseki

I've managed to configure and run jena-fuseki. I used the config-tdb-text.ttl and created a lucene index over the books.ttl example. However when I execute the query

```
    PREFIX text: <http://jena.apache.org/text#>
    PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
    PREFIX book: <http://example.org/book/>
    PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
    PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

    SELECT ?s
    { ?s dc:title ?x .
      ?s text:query  (dc:title 'Harry') ;
    }
```

no tuples are returned.

any idea what I'm missing or doing wrong?

When I executed the following query

```
    SELECT ?s { ?s dc:title ?x . }
```

I did get results. The data I'm using is the books.ttl that comes with jena-fuseki and the config file was slightly modified as follows:

```
    <#entMap> 
        a text:EntityMap ; 
        text:entityField "uri" ; 
        text:defaultField "text" ; 
        text:map ( 
          [ text:field "text" ; 
            text:predicate dc:title; 
            text:analyzer [ 
               a text:StandardAnalyzer ; 
                 text:stopWords ("a" "an" "and" "but") ] ] ) .
```

Comment: We need more information.  Is there any data in the default graph?  If there's not, then you certainly shouldn't expect any results...

Comment: When I executed the following query 

    SELECT ?s
    { ?s dc:title ?x .
    }  I did get results. The data I'm using is the books.ttl that comes with jena-fuseki and the config file was slightly modified as follows:             
<#entMap> a text:EntityMap ;
    text:entityField      "uri" ;
    text:defaultField     "text" ;        
    text:map (          
         [  text:field "text" ; 
             text:predicate dc:title;
             text:analyzer [
               a text:StandardAnalyzer ;
               text:stopWords ("a" "an" "and" "but")
           ]
         ]
         ) .

Comment: It's next to impossible to read codein comments.  Please use the "edit" link under you question and add the additional information to the question.